# How to calculate integrated path?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

So if I have a set of multiple `{distance, angle}` represented in the photo by `{a,A}`, `{b,B}`, `{c,C}`. How can I calculate the distance of the dotted line with the `?` by it?

[image]

Comment: Very simple. _Break_ each vector into components, _add_ them, take _magnitude_.

Comment: Not very helpful. If it were "very simple", then the OP would not have asked. One person's "simple" is another person's "baffling."

Comment: @ParclyTaxel how do you translate the `Angle` and `distance` into a vector point?

Comment: I then will have three of these vector points and I sum them to give me the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $?$ is a vector in the plane. Then it has an x-component, $?_x$, and a y-component, $?_y$. Then
$$?_x=a\cos(A)+b\cos(A+B)\\ +c\cos(A+B+C)$$ and 
$$?_y=a\sin(A)+b\sin(A+B)+c\sin(A+B+C).$$ Then the length of $?$ is $\sqrt{(?_x)^2+(?_y)^2}$. I drew a picture to find the x-component of ?.

[image: I drew a picture to find the x component of ?.]

Comment: Thank you very much! I am now a little bit confused as what the angles will actually be for example I was thinking that angle A is -45 as it is 45 degrees left and if it went right at any point it would be positive. What should they actually be? Or is that fine?

Comment: @Maximilian In this case, it is standard among mathematicians to denote an angle in a counter clockwise direction with respect to the horizontal. Of course, you can choose a different horizontal if you like. You can even decide to measure angles counter clockwise, it would not change the length of ?, as long as you are consistent! Thus if line a makes a 45 degree angle with the horizon, we say that A is +45 degrees.

Comment: @Maximilian See the picture.

Comment: Thank you so much! But what if there was to be a zig zag set of vectors would I be saying 45, -90, 45? Do you understand?

Comment: Or if say the vectors performed a circle along the way?

Comment: @Maximilian Then the same equations apply! Just use A=45, B=-90 and C=45. Maybe you can try a few examples for which you know the answer in advance to verify this for yourself.

Comment: @Maximilian If they form a circle, (for example A=30, B=120 and C=30, with a=b=c=1 unit length), we should have that ? has length 0. Check this yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use coordinates, with the bottom point labelled $(0,0)$, and $x$ increasing to the right, and $y$ increasing upwards. I'll use $A$ to denote the angle, and $A_p$ to denote the coordinates of the point.

Point $A$ is at location $A_p = (0,0)$. 
Point $B$ is at location
$$
B_p = (0,0) + (a \cos(A), a \sin(A))= A_p + a  (\cos(A), \sin(A))
$$
Point $C$ is at location
$$
C_p = B_p + (b \cos (A+B), b \sin(A+B))
$$
and point $D$ is at location 
$$
D_p = C_p + (c \cos (A + B + C), c \sin (A + B+C))
$$
I'm going to assume you have actual values for all these numbers, so you can work out the coordinates for point $D_p$ using these formulas.

The resulting point $D_p$ has coordinates $(x, y)$ for some $x$ and $y$, and the distance to point $A_p$ is 
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The first vector has length a and makes angle A with the x-axis (horizontal).  Its components are (a cos(A), a sin(A)).  The second vector has length b and makes angle B with that first vector.  The angle it makes with the x-axis is A+ B.  This vector has components (b cos(A+ B), b sin(A+ B)).  The third vector has length c and makes angle C with the second vector.  The angle it makes with the x-axis is A+ B+ C.  Its components are (c cos(A+ B+ C), c sin(A+ B+ C)).

Their sum is the vector with components (an cos(A)+ b cos(A+ B)+ c cos(A+ B+ C), a sin(C)+ b sin(A+ B)+ c sin(A+ B+ C)).